# How to attach javadoc or specify javadoc location in eclipse automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

I generated my package mypackage.jar and mypackage-javadoc.jar.

And then I followed instruction [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/110420/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx).

I created mypackage.jar.properties and inside

```
doc=docs/mypackage-javadoc.jar
```

now I placed my package in libs and javadoc jar file into libs/docs/

and then when I import mypackage.jar into my project.

it still says 'This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found'.

Is there anyway to sync javadoc with my class files automatically when I just import mypackage.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo don't need a properties file. Make sure your JAR is added to the classpath of the project (Right click, Properties, Java Build Path).
Then you should see your Jar under the project's node in the tree with a little jar icon next to it. Right-click on it, properties and there is a GUI for setting the Javadoc location.

[image: Adding a JAR]

Click on Javadoc location and then Edit...
[image: Adding a Javadoc]

Enter the path to your javadoc JAR.

Comment: Yes I know how to attach javadoc from the build path. But I was asking if there is anyway for eclipse to know the javadoc location by adding only my package(jar). In other words, I want my user can see javadoc without attaching javadoc by themselves.

Comment: If you use Maven for building, there is a way to configure your build path, javadocs and source for your binary JAR dependencies automatically. There is an Eclipse integration for Maven (called m2e) that updates your projects automatically. I have been using it for years.
Other build tools like Gradle should also support something like that but I honestly don't know.